# How can I get user's facebook interests?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get interest from Facebook Api but empty array is returned.

I have searched for other issues like:

- How to get user Interests? (//stackoverflow.com/questions/12422714/how-to-get-user-interests)
- How can I get the interests of my friend through facebook api?(//stackoverflow.com/questions/6587373/how-can-i-get-the-interests-of-my-friend-through-facebook-api)

In "Graph API Reference" (developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1) is defined a full list of nodes. If I click in 'user' and click in 'interest' I am redirected to "/{user-id}/interests" (//developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/interests) description. In this description are defined serveral points:

- Endpoint: GET /user/interests
- Permission: user_interests
- Descrption: The interests listed on someone's profile under "Likes > Interests" (//www.facebook.com/me/likes_interests).

I am using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) for to test. I have used all api versions (from unversioned to v2.1).

If I get a valid access token with aproppiated permission and I do a request to endpoint "**/me**" I have a successfully response with data.

If I do a request to endpoint "**/me/interests**" I have a empty response:

```
{
"data": [
  ]
}
```

My user in Facebook is following a list of interest for example: [stackoverflow group](https://www.facebook.com/lists/4462173921197).

If I do a request to movies or books the response are empty too. But if I do a "like action" in a book or movie and try again I have a successfull response. If I try again with "**/me/interest**" response is empty yet.

I believe that I do not understand concept of "interest" or something is wrong and I can not see it.

Which is the way for to recovery the interests of an user?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/440058336033758/

Answer (score 0):

The interests are specified in the Profile section, and not via Like actions! The list you linked is not an interest either.

Books and Movies can be requested with the `user_likes` permission, so if you didn't request that the response will be empty as well.

Comment: When I login in Facebook I can see a section in left column with the title "INTERESTS". Is this insterest section considered as interests of an user?

Endpoints "/me/books" and "/me/moovies" are a filter lists from likes but this is not an user's insterest.

what are user's interests? places? sports? music? films? (without a liked action).

Comment: Interests are not really of any use anymore. Likes is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'll use likes and remove interest.